# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 000D526F

Tags: java, exception, serialization, deserialization, java.util.scanner

I am working on a school project which basically allows the user to create a student and write the info into a file, display the student reading from the file and then edit the student info selecting the id of the student that we wish to edit. I got the create student part, the display part was working good but I had a problem with editing, they told me to edit parts of the file is better if we write them in the file as serialized objects so I changed the create student to write them as objects but now I am not able to read from the       file and I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 000D526F
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:966)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:405)
at MidTermProject.DisplayStudent(MidTermProject.java:241)
at MidTermProject.main(MidTermProject.java:355)
```

Any ideas on how can I fix this? here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;
public class MidTermProject implements Serializable {
    
    static AtomicInteger idGenerator = new AtomicInteger(0001);
    static int id;
    
    public static int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public static String CreateStudent() throws IOException {
        String FullName;
        String address;
        String city;
        String state;
        String newStudentID;
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        FileOutputStream fstream =
                new FileOutputStream("StudentInfo.dat", true);
        ObjectOutputStream outputFile =
                new ObjectOutputStream(fstream);
        
        id = idGenerator.getAndIncrement();
        String student = Integer.toString(getId());
        outputFile.writeObject(student);
        
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter your information bellow.\n" + "\nFull Name: ");
        FullName = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputFile.writeObject(FullName);
        
        System.out.print("Address: ");
        address = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputFile.writeObject(address);
        
        System.out.print("City: ");
        city = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputFile.writeObject(city);
        
        System.out.print("State: ");
        state = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputFile.writeObject(state);
    
        outputFile.close();
        
        System.out.print("\nDone\n");
        
        return CreateStudent();
        
    }
    public static void EditStudent() throws IOException {
        String editName;
        String editaddress;
        String editCity;
        String editState;
        int editID;
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter the ID of the student you would like to edit: ");
        editID = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        RandomAccessFile file = 
            new RandomAccessFile("StudentInfo.dat", "rw");
        file.seek(10);
            
        char ch = file.readChar();
            
        if(editID == ch) {
            System.out.print("\nPlease enter NEW information bellow.\n" + "\nFull Name: ");
            editName = keyboard.nextLine();
            file.writeUTF(editName);
                
            System.out.print("Address: ");
            editaddress = keyboard.nextLine();
            file.writeUTF(editaddress);
                
            System.out.print("City: ");
            editCity = keyboard.nextLine();
            file.writeUTF(editCity);
                
            System.out.print("State: ");
            editState = keyboard.nextLine();
            file.writeUTF(editState);
                
            file.close();
                
            System.out.print("Successfully Edited");
        } else {
            System.out.print("error");
        }
    }
    public static void DisplayStudent() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("StudentInfo.dat");
        ObjectInputStream inputFile = new ObjectInputStream(fstream);
        
        MidTermProject student;
        boolean endOfFile = false;
        
        while(!endOfFile)
        {
            try
            {
                student = (MidTermProject) inputFile.readObject();
                System.out.print(student + "\n");
            }
            catch (EOFException | ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                endOfFile = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nDone");
        
        inputFile.close();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        
        int start = 0;
        
        while(start >= 0) {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            System.out.println("Here is the sample of menu choices for Main Menu.");
            
            System.out.println("\nWelcome to University Enrollment" + "\n1. Create Student" +
                                "\n2. Create Course" + "\n3. Create Enrollment" + "\n4. Edit Student" + "\n5. Edit Course"
                                + "\n6. Edit Enrollment" + "\n7. Display Student" + "\n8. Display Course" + "\n9. Display Enrollment"
                                + "\n10. Grades Sub Menu" + "\n0. --- Quit ---");
            
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid choice(1-10, 0 to Quit) :");
            int userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
            
                if(userInput == 1) {
                    CreateStudent();
                } else if(userInput == 2) {
                    CreateCourse();
                } else if(userInput == 3) {
                    CreateEnrollment();
                } else if(userInput == 4 ) {
                    EditStudent();
                } else if(userInput == 5) {
                    EditCourse();
                } else if(userInput == 6) {
                    EditEnrollment();
                } else if(userInput == 7) {
                    DisplayStudent();
                } else if(userInput == 8) {
                    DisplayCourse();
                } else if(userInput == 9) {
                    DisplayEnrollment();
                } else if(userInput == 10) {
                    GradesSubMenu();
                } else if(userInput == 0) {
                    System.out.print("Done\n");
                } else {
                    while(userInput > 10) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid Option, Please try again.");
                        userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
                        if(userInput == 1) {
                            CreateStudent();
                        } else if(userInput == 2) {
                            CreateCourse();
                        } else if(userInput == 3) {
                            CreateEnrollment();
                        } else if(userInput == 4 ) {
                            EditStudent();
                        } else if(userInput == 5) {
                            EditCourse();
                        } else if(userInput == 6) {
                            EditEnrollment();
                        } else if(userInput == 7) {
                            DisplayStudent();
                        } else if(userInput == 8) {
                            DisplayCourse();
                        } else if(userInput == 9) {
                            DisplayEnrollment();
                        } else if(userInput == 10) {
                            GradesSubMenu();
                        } else if(userInput == 0) {
                            System.out.print("Done\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
    }
```

Comment: I am pretty sure it is something related with processing the new ```StudentInfo.dat```, but you need to debug that.

Comment: @Alex I was just trying to figure out how to make it work the display, changed that method to void and removed the return statement and back to how it was, I am trying to figure out that error mentioned before, the return statement has nothing to do with it

Comment: Well when you create Student you are using `ObjectOutputStream`; when you edit student you are using `RandomAccessFile`; when you display student you are using `ObjectInputStream` - thats the issue

Comment: @Alex according to the book starting out with Java which is the one the course is based on, ObjectOutputStream is to write serialized objects and ObjectInputStream is to read, have not made it to edit yet with serialized objects

Comment: I believe it has something to do with `MidTermProject student;` and `student = (MidTermProject) inputFile.readObject();` on the `DisplayStudent` method

Comment: `ObjectOutputStream is to write serialized objects and ObjectInputStream is to read` - of course. But when you edit student you are using `RandomAccessFile` which is absolutely different than `ObjectOutputStream`

Comment: @Alex before using `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` I was using `DataOuputStream` and `DataInputStream` to write and read objects and the idea of `RandomAccessFile` was to move the file pointer to a point of the file so it can be edited, example, editing the address or something like that, never got it to work so somebody mentioned it would be easier to make editing if the objects are serialized that is why I changed to `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` I am guessing I will have to add `ObjectInputStream` to read the file and then `ObjectOutputStream` to write new data

Comment: Besides if you wish to read `MidTermProject` you should write it, but not its parts. https://www.baeldung.com/java-serialization